# Diagonalising a symmetric matrix and diagonalizing a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

Suppose I have a field $K$ which has characteristic $0$. I have read that then every quadratic form over $K$ is diagonalisable over $K$. But on the other hand, I was getting from this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118680/over-which-fields-are-symmetric-matrices-diagonalisable that symmetric matrices may not be diagonalisable over some field of characteristic $0$.

I guess I was thinking that: a quadratic form is diagonalisable if and only if the symmetric matrix associated to it is diagonalisable...  So there seems to be some kind of mistake here, and I am not sure where at the moment.

I would greatly appreciate if you could point out where my error(s) is.
Thank you very much.

Comment: where did you read the result about the quadratic forms?

Comment: I thought I saw it at couple places... One example was here page 3 http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~twm/MTH6140/la26.pdf

Comment: The difference is that diagonalization of the quadratic form $x^TAx$ would be a change of variable $x=Py$, which gives a new form $y^T(P^TAP)y$. While the diagonalization that they are talking in your first link is of linear maps $y=Ax$, which come from a change of variable $x=Px'$, $y=Py'$. This one changes the map to $y'=P^{-1}APx'$. It is two different questions: "Make $P^TAP$ diagonal, with $P$ invertible.", "Make $P^{-1}AP$ diagonal with $P$ invertible."

Comment: @spiralstotheleft I see! So the two notions are actually different! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they are different. There is a connection, of course, if you manage to find a $P$ for one of then such that $P^{-1}=P^T$, then it solves both problems.